# PayPal IPN - What if website email address differs from PayPal account email address?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am about to set up an IPN script after users make a purchase from my site but I just had a thought, what if the email address they signed up to my site with differs from the email address they signed up to PayPal with?

i.e. they sign up to my site with forename.surname@domain.com but their PayPal account login is surname.forename@domain.com.

The PayPal IPN will send back surname.forename@domain.com and I have no way to identify who has just made that purchase.

I realise in this simple case it may be possible to find an email address similar to that in the database but in the real world people have crazy email addresses and that isn't always going to be possible.

Has anyone solved this problem before?

Answer (score 5):

It may be best to use a different identifier such as an invoice number or pass a custom value to PayPal for the payment. PayPal will return this via IPN and can be used to link the payment to the customer's account on your website.

This way you pass a value to PayPal that is linked back to that customer's account regardless of their PayPal account details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was wondering this, so if I send a hidden input in the paypal form, this will come back via the ipn?

Comment: Yes, you can add the hidden fields invoice or custom to the form and it'll appear in the IPN as well.

Comment: To add; this only works for certain parameters which PayPal supports as 'passthrough parameters', such as `<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='xxxx'>` - you cannot arbitrarily create hidden parameters by your own and expect these to be returned.

Comment: that's the correct answer... use the invoice number or the custom field.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should force the customers log in before placing an order, then you can get the email they used in Paypal from the return value, and combine the two emails in some way or even just leave them.